# How to get select option value from javascript to jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

My html is having a selection option value box,if i select any option from that box ,i will get value in javascript but i want this value in jsp because using this string i am showing selected rows from database,i tried request.getparameter also but didn't work
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAppId()
{
  var value=document.getElementById("planeselect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="application Id:"+value;

}
</script>

<select id="planeselect" onchange="getAppId()">
        <%
             Set<String> set=appsList.keySet();
            for (String s:set) {
                String appName = (String) appsList.get(s);
        %>
        <option value="<%=s%>"><%=appName%></option>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

On change you can load the page and use *request.getParameter()*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAppId()
{
  var value=document.getElementById("planeselect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="application Id:"+value;
  window.location="URL_of_this_page?RequiredValue="+value;
 }
</script>

<%
     String ValueRequired=request.getParameter("RequiredValue");
     if(ValueRequired!=null){
               *****operation which you want to perform*****
      }
%>  

    <select id="planeselect" onchange="getAppId()">
    <% 
        Set<String> set=appsList.keySet();
        for (String s:set) {
            String appName = (String) appsList.get(s);
    %>
    <option value="<%=s%>"><%=appName%></option>
    <%
        }
    %>
   </select>
```